# How to display data from current user that's logged in

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to display the events of the user that is currently logged on
    How do I do that?
    Here is my code:
    This is my Model

```
public Event()
{
    Venues = new HashSet<Venue>();
    Ratings = new HashSet<Rating>();
}

public int EventID { get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength(50)]
[Display(Name="Event Name")]
public string EventName { get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength(100)]
[Display(Name = "Event Description")]
public string EventDesc { get; set; }

[Column(TypeName = "image")]
[Display(Name = "Event Logo")]
public byte[] EventLogo { get; set; }

[StringLength(50)]
[Display(Name = "Event Location")]
public string EventLocation { get; set; }

public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }
```

Here is my controller:

```
public ActionResult ManageEvent()
{
    if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
    }

    var events = db.Events;
    return View(events.ToList());
}
```

Here is my View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Project_Touchee.Models.Event>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Manage Events";
}
<h2>Manage All Events</h2>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>

            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EventLogo)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EventName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EventDesc)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EventLocation)
            </th>
     @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @{
            byte[] eventt = item.EventLogo;
            string imageSrc = null;
            if (item.EventLogo != null)
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                ms.Write(eventt, 0, eventt.Length);
                string imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
                imageSrc = string.Format("data:image/index;base64,{0}", imageBase64);

            }
                    }
                    <img src="@imageSrc" width="100" height="100" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EventName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EventDesc)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EventLocation)
                </td>
```

This should only display the events that the current user created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to get a copy of the current user:

```
var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

Then, you need to query the events using that:

```
var events = db.Events.Where(m => m.AspNetUser == user);
```

You can make your life simpler by adding a navigation property to `AspNetUser` for events:

```
public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
```

Then, you can just use: `user.Events`

Comment: Generic type error at "UserManager" requires 2 type arguments

Comment: You're referencing the type rather than the instance. In the default Identity setup, `UserManager(IUserStore<TUser>)` is instantiated as `UserManager` on the controller.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this can you perhaps explain it more thoroughly if you don't mind

Comment: The error you're getting is from trying to use the `UserManager` type directly instead of an instance of that type. Since you are new to this, then you should really be using the default Identity setup instead of trying to implement it from scratch (new MVC 5 Project with Individual Auth). You might also consider starting with the IdentitySamples nuget. Regardless, you need to instantiate `UserManager`. I wrote the code the way I did because the default project has a controller property called `UserManager` that already provides an implementation.